# Can't insert background photo

Tags: html, css, background

I have a png file named light.png

I want this as my background picture (and somewhat transparent) on my site. How does it work?

My css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("light.png");
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white
}
```

Comment: Have you tried opacity?
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I tried something else now. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where do you place your image?
You have to give the correct path of your image.Once check it.
like

```
body {
    background-image: url("../media/light.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white }
```

Comment: let me know your folder structure

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
body{
  top: 0;
  position: fixed; 
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  background: url(/images/landing_image.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```